# jkit gallery issue with loading Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have spent the last few days attempting to get [Jkit Gallery](http://jquery-jkit.com/commands/gallery.html) to work on a side project. I have no clue as to where I may have mis-stepped even after starting from scratch. Here is the link to my[test page](http://gabrielpendleton.com/test2/testSite/) Gallery Test. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In your head tag, you need to include Jquery first before loading the jkit plugins,

like so :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jkit.1.1.21.min.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I was able to get it working. My problem was just that I was using extra code that the JavaScript was supposed to generate.

When I was using the DOM, I brought over extra code that I thought I needed. That code ended up being code I was supposed to only generate when the script was called, not manually implemented.